# Как мне узнать номер строки в файле и забрать из нее данные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

У меня есть 2 файла. В одном и в другом построчно написаны данные. Мне нужно взять определенную строку в одном файле и по номеру строки найти данные в другом файле (может это можно сделать и не по номеру строки). Можете объяснить как это лучше сделать в плане кода. При том что в файлах разные данные и каждая строка одного файла связана с каждой строкой другого. Мне нужно взять данные из второго файла, зная в каком ряду нужные мне данные в первом файле.

**Первый файл:**

```
14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf;31 
0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9;3 
3Dxvjt7N8sbeUoTbASF5dBqEeSMc1o7Pk1;12 
0x944680402B2Ba554f978714b6039755ED10e7466;8
```

**Второй файл:**

```
0.0
0.0
7.91778246
0.5476858867775038
```

Comment: readlines() читает строки и выдает их в виде списка, откуда элементарно взять по номеру любую строку.

Comment: @Эникейщик А как мне узнать номер строки в первом файле?

Comment: Откуда я знаю. Прочитайте.  Я-то вашего файла не видел.

Comment: Приведите примеры строк первого и второго файла. Из описания ничего толком непонятно

Comment: @CrazyElf Добавил

Comment: допустим мы взяли строку `3Dxvjt7N8sbeUoTbASF5dBqEeSMc1o7Pk1;12` и что надо найти во втором файле ?

Comment: @S.Nick `7.91778246`

Comment: @fantazy А почему именно это?

Comment: @MBo Каждая строка одного файла относиться к каждой строке другого файла

Comment: Этот вопрос являет собой хороший пример такого запутанного описания, что даже непонятно, что требуется. А требуется на самом деле вот что: вывести построчно два файла. Первую строку с первой, вторую со второй, третью с третьей и т.д. Вы даже с нескольких раз не смогли ответить на этот простой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
line = 2

with open("fil1_1.txt", "r") as f1, open("fil1_2.txt", "r") as f2:
    rows_1 = f1.readlines()
    rows_2 = f2.readlines()

if len(rows_1) > line and len(rows_2) > line:
    print(f'стоке                {rows_1[line]}'
          f'соответствует строка {rows_2[line]} (соответствие по номеру записи)')
```

---

> А как мне узнать номер строки в первом файле? Или может как то по другому можно решить вопрос?

```
rows_1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4',]

rows_1.index('item1')  # 0
rows_1.index('item2')  # 1
rows_1.index('item3')  # 2
# ...
```

Comment: А как мне узнать номер строки в первом файле? Или может как то по другому можно решить вопрос?

Comment: @fantazy я добавил некоторый пример в ответ

Comment: А если у меня неизвестно количество строк?

Comment: @fantazy зачем вам количество строк? У вас есть содержимое строки, например `3Dxvjt7N8sbeUoTbASF5dBqEeSMc1o7Pk1;12`,  подставьте ее в `rows_1.index('3Dxvjt7N8sbeUoTbASF5dBqEeSMc1o7Pk1;12')` и вы узнаете индекс под которым эта строка находится с списке.

Comment: У меня все не так просто. Функция находит нужные ряды сама (может быть несколько сразу). Или просто через переменную сделать?

Comment: @fantazy если у вас возникают сложности с реализацией алгоритма, я вам  рекомендую задать новый вопрос, в котором приведите воспроизводимый пример с вашей функцией. В нем расскажите что вы делаете и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Если файл большой

```
with open("first file", "r") as first, open("second file", "r") as second:
    while True:
        try:
            f_line = next(first).strip()
            s_line = next(second).strip()
            print(f_line, s_line)
        except StopIteration:
            exit(0)
```

Если не большой)

```
with open("first file", "r") as first, open("second file", "r") as second:
    one = (x.strip() for x in first)
    two = (x.strip() for x in second)
    coins = dict(zip(one, two))

print(coins)
```